# Reverse of Cauchy-Schwarz for two vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, vectors, machine-learning, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

If $\|x\|_2\leq g\|y\|_2$, then according to Cauchy-Schuarz, the maximum of $ \langle x,y \rangle$ would be $ g\|y\|_2^2$

$$
\langle x,y \rangle \leq g\|y\|_2^2
$$
Can we prove the reverse, i.e., if $\langle x,y \rangle \leq g\|y\|_2^2$, then
$$
\|x\|_2\leq g\|y\|_2
$$

Answer (score 2):

No -- if $x$ is orthogonal to $y$, we can make $x$ as big as we want but still have inner product $0$